# Django polymorphic relation pointing directly to records in related models

Tags: django, django-models, polymorphism, django-polymorphic

Im my django application I have following models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ...

class CustomMetric(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, db_column="id", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='custom_metrics')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    function = models.TextField()


class StoreData(model.Model):
    ...


class CarData(model.Model):
    ...
```

If customer adds new custom_metric, it should save this record and based on column function (which is written in string formula for example `cost * 5`), calculate it for each record in `StoreData` and `CarData` models and somehow save this value to database(I can't calculate it on run, because these functions are very complex).

I was thinking about adding new model called `CustomMetricsValues` and use `django-polymorphic`. Something like that:

```
class CustomMetricsValue(model.Model):
   custom_metric = models.ForeignKey(CustomMetric, db_column="id", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='custom_metric_values')
   value = models.FloatField() # here I would save calculated value
   related_field = FK # here somehow I should store information about for which table and which record is that (for example table StoreData record id 2)
```

But I failed because it only saved information regarding which table this record is related(for example `StoreData` but, it doesn't tell for wchich record from this table this custom value belongs. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any better solution?

I don't want to add new table per every related model because in future I will be adding more of them. Also cannot merge `CarData` and `StoreData` into one table.